# Why does struts 2 call set() method in action class twice?

Tags: struts2, action, setter, getter

I've used the something like this in `struts.xml` :

```
action name="{product}/{product-name}/info"
class="myclass"
.. and so on...
```

I added the getter and setter methods for the parameters `product` and `product-name`. On logging I found out that the set method for both the parameters are being called twice (for each parameter). Why is that so?

Comment: Post the stacktrace each time you set the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Probably in your interceptor stack you have declared `params` interceptor twice.

And it could be perfectly right.

The `paramsPrepareParamsStack` is one of the stacks available in the `struts-default.xml` and it's very useful when you are implementing `Model-Driven-CRUD`:
The first `params` interceptor sets the ID of your model, then the `prepare` retrieves the model from the database (or whatever), then the *second* `params` interceptor sets all the incoming attributes of the model (imagine you are reading a `POST`)

From the documentation :

> This is useful for when you wish to apply parameters directly to an object that you wish to load externally (such as a DAO or database or service layer), but can't load that object until at least the ID parameter has been loaded. By loading the parameters twice, you can retrieve the object in the prepare() method, allowing the second params interceptor to apply the values on the object.